# Socket.IO session authentification

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need to connect from client (Website) and recieve messages from Socket.IO NodeJS server when not logged-in and be able to send messages to server when logged-in.

I see, Other sites using "**express.sid**" cookie to authentificate client. Client not sending any message with this SID line `io.emit("hash", cookie)`, but server somehow knows who connecting in and if user is logged.

How to achieve this on server-side?

EDIT: I found this: npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session, I made Example work but now I am stuck what I need to do next to have cookie saved in browser and decide if user is logged or not

Answer (score 0):

I learned about nodejs express server developing and now I know how to achieve what I asked.

For other people:
If you want use sessions with Socket.IO use `express-socket.io-session` package.
Make Node.js app with `express` and develop your app here. Not PHP :)